# Pass a laravel variable into a jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am trying to pass a variable into a jquery autocomplete script check this url (https://jsfiddle.net/duoc5bbh/1/) I found.

Autocomplete Form

```
<input id="name" >
<input id="email" >
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $value = Person::where('active', 'online')->get();
    return view('users.index', ['data' => $value]);
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
  let users = [{
      "email": "marie@gmail.com",
      "name": "marie"
      }, 
      {
       "email": "miss@gmail.com",
       "name": "miss"
     }];
});
```

what I did

```
$(function() {
  let users = [{
      "email": {{ $value-> email }},
      "name": {{ $value-> name }}
      }];
                    function handleAutocomplete(term) {
                        // use 'term' for custom filtering etc.
                        let options = $.grep(users, function(e){ return e.name.startsWith(term); });
                        return options;
                    }
                    $("#name").autocomplete({
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            let name = request.term;
                            let data = handleAutocomplete(name); /* get answers from somewhere.. */
                            response(data);
                        },
                        focus: function(event, ui) {
                            $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
                            return false;
                        },

                        select: function(event, ui) {
                            $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
                            $("#email").val(ui.item.email);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                        return $("<li>")
                            .append("<a>" + item.name + "<br>" + item.email + "</a>")
                            .appendTo(ul);
                    };
                });
```

I change this

```
  let users = [{
      "email": {{ $value-> email }},
      "name": {{ $value-> name }}
      }]
```

To this

```
let users = '{{ json_encode($data) }}'
```

Still did not work

This is what I want to achieve (https://jsfiddle.net/duoc5bbh/1/) but with my data from database.

I am new in using laravel with jquery I need your help in this Thanks.

Comment: try using `let users = '{{ json_encode($data) }}'` and see what you get.

Comment: Hi @BhaumikPandhi I have made the change but still know result see my full code above

Comment: did you also fix the typo `['data' => $person]` ?

Comment: Yes I did, this is what I want to achieve (https://jsfiddle.net/duoc5bbh/1/) but with my data from database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo out the json_encoded variable and transform it to a js object with `JSON.parse()`.

```js
let users = JSON.parse('{{ json_encode($data) }}');
```

Laravel also used to provide the `@json` directive to help with that.

```js
let users = JSON.parse('@json($data)');
```

Now, the documentation points to a new `Js` facade.

> ## Rendering JSON
>
> Sometimes you may pass an array to your view with the intention of rendering it as JSON in order to initialize a JavaScript variable. For example:
>
> ```
> <script>
>     var app = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
> </script>
> ```
>
> However, instead of manually calling json_encode, you may use the  `Illuminate\Support\Js::from` method directive. The from method accepts the same arguments as PHP's `json_encode` function; however, it will ensure that the resulting JSON is properly escaped for inclusion within HTML quotes. The from method will return a string `JSON.parse` JavaScript statement that will convert the given object or array into a valid JavaScript object:
>
> ```xml
> <script>
>     var app = {{ Illuminate\Support\Js::from($array) }};
> </script>
> ```
>
> The latest versions of the Laravel application skeleton include a Js facade, which provides convenient access to this functionality within your Blade templates:
>
> ```
> <script>
>     var app = {{ Js::from($array) }};
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Hi @IGP Thanks for your respond, I have made the change but still know result see my full code above

Comment: Is your jquery code in the same blade file as the view or is it a separate .js file?

Comment: both are in the same blade file